# Visual Studio 2015 Publish to file system with only changed files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, publish

I have an asp.net mvc project with lots of .css and .js files in it. I would like to fasten my publishing process.

My publishing method is File System and the target is a server on my network.

The path is something like \\10.0.0.1\c$\inetpub

But Visual studio is publishing all files on my solution when I select "Publish to file system". It doesn't publish only changed files.

I just would like to publish only changed files. How can I do it?

Comment: have you got "Delete all existing files prior to publish" ticked in the File Publish options?

Comment: No,  "Delete all existing files prior to publish" is not checked...

Comment: I have same problem and my "Delete all existing files prior to publish" is checked. 

@oneNiceFriend were you able to find out how?

Comment: No. File system publishing doesnt allow that. Instead you can use Web Deploy publishing method. Web deploy publishes only changed files.